# Convert json filtered into csv with jq

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have file that looks like this:

```sh
$ cat sample-test.json |jq .
{
  "logRef": "c4fa4367-23f6-462f-b5fd-f972d0916a30",
  "timestamp": 1563268297545,
  "someOtherField": "nonImportantValue"
}
{
  "logRef": "c4fa4367-23f6-462f-b5fd-f972d0916a31",
  "timestamp": 1563268297595,
  "someOtherField2": "nonImportantValue3"
}
```

And I would like to convert it to csv like this:

```
logRef;timestamp
c4fa4367-23f6-462f-b5fd-f972d0916a30;1563268297545
c4fa4367-23f6-462f-b5fd-f972d0916a31;1563268297595
```

I was trying

```sh
$ cat sample-test.json |jq '.logRef, .timestamp |@csv'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): string ("c4fa4367-2...) cannot be csv-formatted, only array
jq: error (at <stdin>:2): string ("c4fa4367-2...) cannot be csv-formatted, only array
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input is fine (it's a JSON stream).

The problem with your filter is that `@csv` expects an array.  So this will work:

```
[.logRef,.timestamp] | @csv
```

However it quotes strings, so if you want your strings unquoted (which might mean the result won't be CSV), then you could use:

```
"\(.logRef),\(.timestamp)"
```

In all cases, you'll need to use jq's`-r` command-line option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your json file. Looks like it has incorrect format (without root array element `[]` and commas between documents). If you fix it, `jq` will work as expected.

```sh
> cat sample-test.json 
[{
  "logRef": "c4fa4367-23f6-462f-b5fd-f972d0916a30",
  "timestamp": 1563268297545,
  "someOtherField": "nonImportantValue"
},
{
  "logRef": "c4fa4367-23f6-462f-b5fd-f972d0916a31",
  "timestamp": 1563268297595,
  "someOtherField2": "nonImportantValue3"
}]
```

```sh
cat sample-test.json |jq -r 'map(.logRef), map(.timestamp) | @csv'
"c4fa4367-23f6-462f-b5fd-f972d0916a30","c4fa4367-23f6-462f-b5fd-f972d0916a31"
1563268297545,1563268297595
```

I've also fixed the command with `map()` function.

Comment: Please note that jq allows streams of JSON. In a sense, that's the whole point of jq -- it's fundamentally stream-oriented.  You can salvage your answer (somewhat) by suggesting the -s command-line option.  But again, the whole point of jq is that by not requiring the input in this case be an array or converted into a single JSON entity, one can easily handle bigger files than will fit in memory.